# Assembly loaded using Assembly.LoadFrom() on remote machine causes SecurityException

Tags: c#

I am loading an assembly using `Assembly.LoadFrom(fileName)`.  When `fileName` is on the local machine, everything works fine.  When, however, the identical file (and dependencies) are on a remote network share, I get a `System.Security.SecurityException` the moment I try to create a new `SqlConnection` from the remote assembly:

> System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission, System.Data,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.

What's the cure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could load the assembly as bytes and load it with `Assembly.Load(bytes)`, maybe this works.

Or you give the application the requested permission.

#### Edit:

I made a little test and it worked for me. Here is some code:

```
static Dictionary<Assembly, String> _Paths = new Dictionary<Assembly, String>();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AppDomain current = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
    current.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(HandleAssemblyResolve);

    // This line loads a assembly and retrieves all types of it. Only when
    // calling "GetTypes" the 'AssemblyResolve'-event occurs and loads the dependency
    Type[] types = LoadAssembly("Assemblies\\MyDLL.dll").GetTypes();
    // The next line is used to test permissions, i tested the IO-Permissions 
    // and the Reflection permissions ( which should be denied when using remote assemblies )
    // Also this test includes the creation of a Form
    Object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(types[0]);
}

private static Assembly LoadAssembly(string file)
{
    // Load the assembly
    Assembly result = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(file));
    // Add the path of the assembly to the dictionary
    _Paths.Add(result, Path.GetDirectoryName(file));
    return result;
}

static Assembly HandleAssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    // Extract file name from the full-quallified name
    String name = args.Name;
    name = name.Substring(0, name.IndexOf(','));
    // Load the assembly
    return LoadAssembly(Path.Combine(_Paths[args.RequestingAssembly], name + ".dll"));
}
```

#### Something important:

There may be files which do not have a matching name and file name, but you can resolve this by checking all files in folder with `AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(file)`.

Comment: Why do you thinking loading it as bytes would help?  And what do you mean by "give the application the requested permission" - how?

Comment: Because your application does not know where it has been loaded from, maybe this does not restricts the permissions.

Comment: Nice idea - but it fails as soon as you need to call a dependency.  With LoadFrom() we know which folder to look in for required dlls; if we load as bytes we have no idea where to find the other files...

Comment: Simple workaround: The dependency's are loaded when loading the assembly, using the `ResolveAssembly` event and a `Stack<String>` solves the issues with loading the assemblies ( Put the path's in the stack while loading ). Edit: If you need the path at runtime, you could use a `Dictionary<Assembly, String>`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm actually not going to try it, because the solution (workaround, really) I got to is actually a good one, but +1 for the idea, which could well work.  If anyone else tries it and it works, please leave a comment here!

Comment: Well, well - in that case, you have correctly and effectively answered my question, and answer credit belongs to you!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found a workaround.  I could not find any way to circumvent the `SecurityException` problem - so instead of loading the assembly from the remote folder, I simply copied the remote folder contents at runtime to the local computer and ran from there.  Simple, neat and works perfectly.  Plus, it's arguably a better way of working, so that the clients are running off their local copy instead of putting load on the server, and it makes it **much** easier to deploy an updated version of the original, without any file locking.

**Caveat** to anyone who tries to follow in my footsteps: don't try and copy to a subfolder of your app directory; for some reason this causes errors with dependencies.  Rather copy to 'Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)` or some other folder to which you know you have write access.

Answer (score 1):

The assembly is being loaded with LocalIntranet permission set. This restricts certain APIs. See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03kwzyfc.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x4t63kb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the links.  But what do you suggest I do to work around this?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'd be interested to know what it is.

Comment: @spender See last posting on this question. But my solution works also.